# Strpos unexpected result with special characters

Tags: php, html, strpos

I'm trying to **find the position** of the HTML element  in a HTML document.
So i do this:

```
    $filestring = file_get_contents($filename); //get the raw file
    $filestring = htmlspecialchars($filestring);

   $pos = strpos($filestring, "<head>"); //find the position of <head>
   print_r($pos); //print the position
```

End print_r don't show nothing. I think it is due to the special characters, but do not understand how to do.

Comment: If I do this:  $pos = strpos($filestring, "head"); the script work but is not what i want

Comment: What if you use $pos = strpos($filestring, "&lt;head&gt;"); ? htmlspecialchars replaces the < and > with these codes

Comment: Whoa, thanks Pepe!

Comment: If your question was answered, you should "accept " the best answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I already know, but I had to wait minutes to get it. Stackoverflow did not allow me to do so

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such things as `<head>` in $filestring.
When you use htmlspecialchars, the `<` and `>` get replaced:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

```
$pos = strpos($filestring, "&lt;head&gt;");
```

Or don't use htmlspecialchars when searching for the string

Comment: Thanks! it was so obvious.
 The stackoverflow community Rock a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Why do you use `htmlspecialchars`? 
Do you understand that using this function causes all entities like `>` or `<` to be replaces by their representations like `&gt;` or `&lt;`?

So, the solutions are

- either not use `htmlspecialchars`
- or search not for `<head>` but for `&lt;head&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

i think you should remove this line from your code.

```
$filestring = htmlspecialchars($filestring);
```